# Using Postgres JSON Functions on a table row

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I'm stuck with this, so maybe someone can help me with it. I have a table "answers" with two columns id and json_data. In each row of json_data column I have saved object data which looks like this:

firs json_data row:

```
{
    "question161839": {"answer": "test1 answer", "review_answ": "true"}, 
    "question161840": {"answer": "test2 answer", "review_answ": "false"}, 
    "question161841": {"answer": "test3 answer", "review_answ": "true"}, 
}
```

next json_data row:

```
{
    "question161850": {"answer": "test4 answer", "review_answ": "true"}, 
    "question161851": {"answer": "test5 answer", "review_answ": "true"}, 
    "question161852": {"answer": "test6 answer", "review_answ": "false"}, 
    "question161853": {"answer": "test7 answer", "review_answ": "false"}
}
```

I'm looking for Postgres query, which allows me to select a questions where "review_answ" is false.
Something like:

```
select * from answers where json_data->review_answ = false
```

and as a results I'm expecting:

```
question161840, question161852, question161853
```

I Found a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42677415/using-postgres-json-functions-on-table-columns) but I don't understand how to use it in my case.

Comment: Do you want the results in multiple rows, or a single row? Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: If it's possible I'll prefer multiple rows and I'm using Postgres 11.8

Answer (score 1):

You can extract all key/value pairs using `jsonb_each()` the result of that can be filtered using a WHERE condition:

```
select a.id, t.questionid
from answers a
  cross join jsonb_each(a.json_data) t(questionid, details)
where t.details ->> 'review_answ' = 'false'
order by a.id;
```

If your column is defined as `json` rather than `jsonb` (which it should be), you need to use `json_each()` instead.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=76904111f14b7a4a7fdabe952ea15acf)

Answer (score -1):

maybe like this :

select substring(json_data::TEXT,4,14) from answers where json_data ->> review_answ = false

Comment: Thanks but nope, it's not working:
Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  column "review_answ" does not exist

Comment: You only need to change the conditions where like this: SELECT substring(json_data::TEXT,4,14) FROM answers WHERE json_data::TEXT LIKE '%"review_answ": "false"%'

Comment: Thank you for your help - this solution works too!